# Java - HashCode - Equals

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, equals, hashcode

I have a problem with Unit Tests in Java.

I put here my code and my error. On internet I found this is a problem with hashcode. I need to recreate them but I don't know why and how.

**My method :**

```
public void setGroupModel(GroupModel groupModel) {
    this.groupModel = groupModel;
    this.groupModel.add(this);
}
```

**cellControler file :**

```
public class CellController {

    public void click(CellModel cellModel, HexModel hexModel)
    {
        GroupModel groupModel = new GroupModel();
        cellModel.setGroupModel(groupModel);
        hexModel.getGridContentModel().getArrayListGroupModel().add(groupModel);
    }
}
```

**My UnitTest :**

```
public class CellControllerTest {
    protected CellController cellController;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        cellController = new CellController();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
    }

    @Test
    public void testClick() throws Exception{
        GroupModel groupModel = new GroupModel();
        CellModel cellModel = new CellModel();
        HexModel hexModel = new HexModel(); // hexModel has an attribute : gridContentModel
        cellController.click(cellModel, hexModel);
        assertEquals(groupModel, cellModel.getGroupModel());
    }
}
```

**My error**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<model.GroupModel@6d5380c2> but was:<model.GroupModel@45ff54e6>
```

I think the problem is :  **`this.groupModel = groupModel;`**

What I have to write and why? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare is easy, you need to override hashCode and equals or use a comparator, if you did not do that then the message you get is perfectly normal.

Here you set the `groupModel` **AND modify the groupModel.**

```
public void setGroupModel(GroupModel groupModel) {
  this.groupModel = groupModel;
  this.groupModel.add(this); // the modification
}
```

In your test you compare the `groupModel` you just created and the groupModel that you get from `cellModel.getGroupModel()`, but that one has been **modified**, so **the two objects are different**

```
    assertEquals(groupModel, cellModel.getGroupModel());
```